# How to disable button according to input length by using React useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a simple page with input fields and a button and I want to make button disabled when both field length is less than 3. It is simple thing but I am confused about the hook because it is going into infinite loop.
Here is code:

```
function TableFooterPanel(props) {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    // const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

    const addNewCustomer = async (name, surname) => {
        await service.addCustomer(name, surname);
        props.funcParam();
    }

    var isButtonDisabled = false;

    if (firstName <= 3 || lastName <= 3) {
        isButtonDisabled = true;
    }
    else {
        isButtonDisabled = false;
    }

    return (

        <>
            <Card className='buttonFooter'>
                <Form className='buttonFooter'>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" defaultValue={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <Button disabled={isButtonDisabled} onClick={() => addNewCustomer(firstName, lastName)}>Add</Button>
                </Form>
            </Card>

        </>

    );

}
export default TableFooterPanel;
```

With this code, the boxes only check whether they are empty or filled.

If I uncomment useState hook and try to set it in if-else condition then this time *infinite-loop* is happening and page is crashing.

How can I check the input length without falling into infinite-loop?

Comment: Off topic, I know, but setting the limit to 3 characters for a name is extreme. Amy, Abu, Ash, Abe, Sal, Nic, Leo, and Ian aren't going to be happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to not write code directly in component's body: you don't know how many times that code will be exected. Much better use a `useEffect` hook:

```
function TableFooterPanel(props) {

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

const addNewCustomer = async (name, surname) => {
    await service.addCustomer(name, surname);
    props.funcParam();
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (firstName.length <= 3 || lastName.length <= 3) {
       setIsButtonDisabled(true);
   }
   else {
       setIsButtonDisabled(false);
   }
}, [firstName, lastName]);


return (

    <>
        <Card className='buttonFooter'>
            <Form className='buttonFooter'>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" defaultValue={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}></input>
                <Button disabled={isButtonDisabled} onClick={() => addNewCustomer(firstName, lastName)}>Add</Button>
            </Form>
        </Card>

    </>

);

}
export default TableFooterPanel;
```

As you can see, I have used an `useEffect` hook with `firstName` and `lastName` in deps list: this means that, every time `firstName` or `lastName` change, `useEffect` will be fired.

And don't forget that, to check string length you have to use `length` property =).

Comment: I would say this is an anti-pattern. You should not create a state variable to keep a variable that can easily be calculated from props or existing state. This is a boolean, and  it would be compared by value. It simply doesn't belong in state.

If it had been an expensive operation, or if the value was an object, which is compared by reference, then it would be better utilising useMemo.

Comment: @GøranCantona What do you mean when you say "antipattern"? Which pattern you are referring to? This is how React works! Maybe you want to say that this is an overskilled approach. Could be but you have to consider that the question could be just an example OP made to solve a bigger problem (because he cannot post all the code)... I answered following React design pattern.

Comment: I'm referring to the pattern of storing derived state as a state variable.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
   if (firstName.length <= 3 || lastName.length <= 3) {
        isButtonDisabled = true;
    }
    else {
        isButtonDisabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-architecture-nu1req?file=/src/App.js)

You could simple add the disabled argument inline like this:

```
            <button
              disabled={firstName.length < 3 || lastName.length < 3}
              onClick={() => addNewCustomer(firstName, lastName)}
            >
              Add
            </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Less than 3 is `< 3`, not `<= 3`

There's no need for an if condition here, just set the value of isButtonDisabled directly:

```
const isButtonDisabled = firstName.lenght < 3 || lastName.lenght < 3;
```

Or just do it inline:

```
<Button disabled={firstName.lenght < 3 || lastName.lenght < 3} />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function TableFooterPanel(props) {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

    const addNewCustomer = async (name, surname) => {
        await service.addCustomer(name, surname);
        props.funcParam();
    }

    return (

        <>
            <Card className='buttonFooter'>
                <Form className='buttonFooter'>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" defaultValue={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <Button disabled={!(firstName.length < 3 || lastName.length < 3)} onClick={() => addNewCustomer(firstName, lastName)}>Add</Button>
                </Form>
            </Card>

        </>

    );

}
export default TableFooterPanel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them inside a `useEffect` otherwise it will re-run when anything on this page changes and make the `isButtonDisabled` variable as a state.

```
const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(true)

useEffect(()=>{
   if (firstName.length <= 3 || lastName.length <= 3) {
       setIsButtonDisabled(true);
   } else {
       setIsButtonDisabled(false);
   }    
},[firstName, lastName])
```